# Inserting custom html tag using javascript pasteHTML function

Tags: javascript, html, paste

I am creating a custom WYSIWYG using editable iframe.I want to add a Custom html tag `<ino>` to a selected text like `<info>`some content here`</info>`.I have used this code

```
Editor = document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.document;
var tag='info'
var range = Editor.selection.createRange();
if (range.pasteHTML)
{
 var content=Editor.selection.createRange().htmlText
 content1="<"+tag+">"+content+"</"+tag+">"
    range.pasteHTML(content1);
}
```

This code is for IE.In `content1` am getting the correct text.But in output, the starting tag `<info>` is not getting .I have created the element using `document.createElement('info');`How i can solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no HTML `<info>` element. This could well be the reason that your code is not working.

If you really need to do this (I can't see why you would), you could take advantage of the fact that IE allows you to create invalid DOM elements using `document.createElement()` and do something like the following, which pastes in a marker element, positions an `<info>` element containing the original TextRange content before the marker element and then removes the marker:

```
var range = Editor.selection.createRange();
var info = Editor.createElement("info");
info.innerHTML = range.htmlText;
var id = "some_random_id";
range.pasteHTML('<span id="' + id + '"></span>');
var span = Editor.getElementById(id);
span.parentNode.insertBefore(info, span);
span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve using `document.createElement('info');`? It's not a valid HTML element, so IE is not creating it when you use `pasteHTML`. It's possible IE will allow you to create and insert an `<info>` element into the DOM, which may seem contradictory, but that's IE for you. The reason why it's not working with `pasteHTML` still stands.

Comment: @ Tim Down :I have a content `<tittle>Some Content Here</tittle>` and and selected the entire content and adding the new tag '<info>' How i can remove the `<title>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

As it says in this link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536656%28VS.85%29.aspx pasteHML only accepts HTML tags.
You can use **innerHTML** property instead:

```
range.innerHTML = content1;
```

Comment: `TextRange` objects do not have an `innerHTML` property.

Comment: @Tim Down:Is any other way like `execCommand("inserthtml",false, content1)`

Comment: @THOmas: see my revised answer.